# Result goes blank while exporting records from mysql to textfile

Tags: php, mysql, file

Here, I am exporting records from mysql to textfile. But I want to fetch that record, result goes blank.
Here is my code:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
   $fo = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   $data_query=mysql_query("SELECT order_id from tbl_order");

   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data_query))
   {
        $stringData.="Order: ".$data['order_id']."\n";
   }
   fwrite($fo, $stringData);
   fclose($fo);
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in your code.

1.) Your variable `stringData` isn't defined before you should do that.

2.) You write your complete output in a variable and that need a lot of memory if you have a lot of records. Its better to write your output directly to your file.

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fo = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
$data_query=mysql_query("SELECT order_id from tbl_order");

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data_query))
{
    fwrite($fo, "Order: ".$data['order_id']."\n");
}
fwrite($fo, $stringData);
fclose($fo);
```

Otherwise its possible that you run over your memory limit and your get a blank page if the error reporting is disabled.